# xsl-fo apply radius to top borders

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

Good day
I have this XSL-FO

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" border-width="0.2mm"  border-color="#330099" border-style="groove" 
            border-collapse="separate" background-color="white" line-height="16pt" space-before.optimum="10pt" 
            space-after.optimum="6pt" text-align="left" >       
                <fo:table-column column-width="37mm"/> 
                <fo:table-column column-width="37mm"/> 
                <fo:table-column column-width="37mm"/> 
                <fo:table-column column-width="37mm"/> 
                <fo:table-column column-width="37mm"/> 
                <!-- <fo:table-column column-width="38mm"/> --> 
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border-width="0.01mm" border-color="#330099"  border-style="groove" background-color="lightgrey">
                    <fo:block text-align="left" color="#000000" font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold">Account Number</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-width="0.01mm" border-color="#330099"  border-style="groove" background-color="lightgrey">
                    <fo:block text-align="left" color="#000000" font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold">Customer Id</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell> 
                <fo:table-cell border-width="0.01mm" border-color="#330099"  border-style="groove" background-color="lightgrey">
                    <fo:block text-align="left" color="#000000" font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold">Account Currency</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-width="0.01mm" border-color="#330099"  border-style="groove" background-color="lightgrey">
                    <fo:block text-align="right" color="#000000" font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold">Opening Balance</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-width="0.01mm" border-color="#330099"  border-style="groove" background-color="lightgrey">
                    <fo:block text-align="right" color="#000000" font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold">Closing Balance</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>

 </fo:table-body>
 </fo:table>
```

my question is: i want to apply rouding borders to this table
is it possible with border-radius ? 
or any other method ?

Comment: Do you use FOP? See http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/extensions.html#rounded-corners and http://wiki.apache.org/xmlgraphics-fop/RoundedBorders (not tested by me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1) Best: Create small SVG images for each corner, then format using a table inside of a table ... the outer table has small left/right columns and top/bottom rows with a large cell in the center. Put your table into the large cell in the center. You can even do this with just four round corner images and a proper application of borders. If you need this structure to carry across a table that breaks over a page, then the corner images need to be in a header/footer in the XSL FO.

Option 2) Almost as good. If you know the width of the table, just a single row top and bottom of the table with the rounded edges and line between, and then match the table in between with appropriate left/right borders for going all around. You only add a single row and cell (spanned all columns) at the start/stop of the table.

Option 3) Depends on your situation ... if the height and width of the tables are fairly consistent, you can just use a rounded corner SVG image as background-image to the table or a block enclosing the table. You can scale it to fit width and height. This method could distort the curves of the corners and this is why it would work only when you know the dimensions of the table before hand (or can at least approximate it. I have also used this method in a document where the height was variable but mathematically known ... that is, the table could have 5 rows or 10 rows or whatever but the width was always consistent ... the XSL is used to "count" the rows and select an appropriate external SVG for the background (like table-bg-row-5.svg ... table-bg-row-10.svg).

Note any or all of these are doable without extensions in XSL FO and allow you to create any type of custom borders in tables, not just rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

Try space-before=5mm space-after=5mm

You can use space-after=5mm in the fo block tag. Example

```
<fo:block space-after=5mm>Something</fo-block>
<fo:block>SomethingSomething</fo:block>
```

The first line will create space of 5 mm after the text "Something".

Answer (score 1):

Try `<fo:block space-after=5mm space-before=5mm>to get space both front and end/fo-block>`